# Error in running instascrape in jupyter notebook

Tags: python

I am running this code to scrape data from Instagram:

```
from instascrape import Location 
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/212988663/new-york-new-york/'
new_york = Location(url)
new_york.scrape()
```

But it's throwing me the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_19132/3754258227.py in <module>
      2 url = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/212988663/new-york-new-york/'
      3 new_york = Location(url)
----> 4 new_york.scrape()
      5 

JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This lib as not been updated since January 2021, [source](https://pypi.org/project/insta-scrape/#history) it is very likely that Instagram changed data format since then. You should open an issue on there repo

Comment: How can I open the issue on there repo?

Comment: [here](https://github.com/chris-greening/instascrape/issues)